# dojo ValidationTextBox tooltipPosition

Tags: javascript, dojo, textbox, position, tooltip

How can I define the position of tooltip in validation text box (by default it is left)?

My code is:

```
var textBox = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
   name : "someName",
   value : "someValue",
   regExp : "someExpression",
   invalidMessage : "someError"
}, "someId");
```

if I add

```
tooltipPosition: "below"
```

then I get an error. I need to show my tooltip below the textbox. How it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter tooltipPosition is expecting an array.  The following should work:

```
var textBox = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
    name : "someName",
    value : "someValue",
    regExp : "someExpression",
    invalidMessage : "someError",
    tooltipPosition: ["below"]
}, "someId");
```

You can supply a list of preferences here, so that Dojo tries to place the tooltip in the best position.  Using, something like:

```
tooltipPosition: ["below","above","after","before"]
```

Might be better as it will display the tooltip below unless there is no-room on the screen.  If there is no room it will then try above, then after, ...etc.

For more information on tooltip positioning see:

- [dijit/Tooltip Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/Tooltip.html)